# Update socket.io handshake data when using angular factory

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io, factory

I'm having some trouble with the handshake data in my angularjs/ionic application when I reconnect a user to my socket.io quiz-application.

I would like to update the handshake-data I'm sending from the client when connection to my server, if a user disconnects and then connects again.
(I need some data in the handshake, because the server checks if the user is joining for the first time, or just lost its connection to the quiz)

**My problem/what happens now:**

1. A user want to join quiz with id "12345"
2. The user connect to my server, sending handshake-data: `{user_id: 1, quiz_code: 12345}`
3. Server then adds the user "1" to quiz number "12345"
4. When the quiz ends, the user uses io.disconnect() and leaves the quiz
5. The user now decides to join the quiz "66666"
6. Now the socket factory seems to remember the old handshake.
7. So when the client connect to the server it sends `{user_id: 1, quiz_code: 12345}` but should have send `{user_id: 1, quiz_code: 66666}`

**My angular.js Controller**

```
.controller('QuizCtrl', function(SocketService) {

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
        //this seems to be the problem -> it reuses the old data in the factory
        SocketService.connect(); 
    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(e) {
        SocketService.removeListener();
        SocketService.disconnect();
    });

});
```

**My angular.js socket factory**

```
.factory('SocketService', function(socketFactory){

     var data = {
         activeQuiz  : {quiz_code: 12345, quiz_ip: some.ip}, 
         currentUser : {user_id: 1}
     };
     //This data is loaded from localStorage in the application, so it can be changed 

     var myIoSocket = io.connect(data.activeQuiz.ip, {query: 'user_id='+data.currentUser.user_id+'&quiz_code='+data.activeQuiz.quiz_code});

     mySocket = socketFactory({
         ioSocket: myIoSocket
     });

     return mySocket;
})
```

So 3 questions:

1. I know factories are singletons, but can I update the data in my factory?
2. Can I "re-inject" the factory to my controller or "reset" the factory when the user enters the controller.
3. Is there a better way to do it maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factories do not *need* to be singletons, and in your case I would indeed suggest them not to be. To do that, all you need to do is wrap your factory logic inside a function, like this:

```
.factory('SocketService', function(socketFactory){
     var init = function() {
         var data = {
             activeQuiz  : {quiz_code: 12345, quiz_ip: some.ip}, 
             currentUser : {user_id: 1}
         };
         //This data is loaded from localStorage in the application, so it can be changed 

         var myIoSocket = io.connect(data.activeQuiz.ip, {query: 'user_id='+data.currentUser.user_id+'&quiz_code='+data.activeQuiz.quiz_code});

         mySocket = socketFactory({
             ioSocket: myIoSocket
         });

         return mySocket;
     }
     return init
})
```

This way, you can assign a `$scope.socketService = SocketConnect()` everytime you want to reset your factory, as you would be instantiating a new object.

Comment: how if i want to insert query parameters using data from database? i'm using $http.get to get the data, but socket return value not waiting the data to be loaded...